# Show that the determinant is n factorial

Tags: matrices, determinant

how can I prove the following problem?

$$\det\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\\
-1 & 1 & 2^2 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & -1 & 1 & 3^2 & \ddots & \vdots\\
\vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & 0\\
0 & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 1 & (n-1)^2\\
0 & \cdots & \cdots & 0 & -1 & 1\end{bmatrix} = n!$$
I'm familiar how to calculate a determinant, but how can I prove this?

Comment: adding 1st row to 2nd row, extract a common factor 2 from 2nd row. add the new 2nd row to 3rd row, extract a common factor 3 from 3rd row... repeat the process until you get n! times determinant of an upper triangular matrix with diagonal equals to 1.

Comment: could you please show the first steps is detail?

Comment: if you add the 1st row to 2nd row, the 2nd row becomes $[ 0, 2, 2^2, 0 \cdots ]$. extract the common $2$, the new 2nd row becomes $[ 0, 1, 2, 0 \cdots ]$. If you add this new row to 3rd row, the 3rd row becomes $[ 0, 0, 3, 3^2, 0,\cdots ]$. see the pattern?

Comment: If $D_n$ is the result and you expand along the last column you get that $D_n=D_{n-1}+(n-1)^2D_{n-2}$, and well $D_1=1$, and $D_2=2$. This is satisfied by $D_n=n!$. By uniqueness of the initial value problem, that is the value of the determinant.

Comment: yes, now I see it, thank you!

Comment: @totoro That should be an answer instead of a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m=n-1$. The matrix has a very nice LU decomposition
$$
\pmatrix{
1\\
-1&2\\
&-1&3\\
&&\ddots&\ddots\\
&&&-1&m\\
&&&&-1&n}
\pmatrix{
1&1\\
&1&2\\
&&1&3\\
&&&\ddots&\ddots\\
&&&&1&m\\
&&&&&1},
$$
which makes its determinant obvious to calculate.